# reducing voltage to power CREE LED headlamp

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I have a LED Headlamp that uses 3AAA batteries that I want to power from a 6v-HD battery what do I need to do to reduce voltage to 4.5v I do not know wattage but it light output is 350 lumens

Comment: You need a constant current led driver (Buck topology).

Comment: Are you going to apply power directly to the LED, or are you going to apply power to the pads where the battery power normally goes?

Comment: this headlight has a power jack that is already connected to the three AAA batteries I was going to leave the 3 AAA in place and just plug in the 6v

Comment: You cannot just connect a 6V power source to 3AAA batteries. It will charge the batteries. If they are alkaline, they are not designed to be charged, and may leak electrolyte or heat up. If they are NiMH, 6V will over-charge them and they will get very hot and probably fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a simple step-down switching regulator that can handle the required small dropout. If the 6V-HD battery puts out less than 4.5 V + V_dropout at some point in time you should consider using a buck-boost converter with either pure buck-boost or SEPIC topology.

The headlamp itself takes care of the LED driving which leads me to another solution. The headlamp probably does already include a constant current buck regulator and could be able to work directly with 6 V on the input, but this is not sure since 5 V is a common upper boundary for the input voltage. Only a risky experiment or a look at the used IC could reveal that.